# Android: Character appearing as a box

Tags: java, android

I have an app displaying Japanese characters but for some reason, the tilde (~) character is displaying as a box (which looks like this, but one character: []).

This is after i apply the text to a TextView. I got the text from a JSON string.

The thing that disturbs me is, aren't Java strings unicode? Anyone know what i need to fix?

```
characters = getCharacterFromJSON();

// set character
TextView charTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.characterView);
charTextView.setText(characters);
```

[image]

```
// Ack! all my ~'s are []!
```

EDIT: it's not a tilde(~), it's a japanese character (〜), which indicates these characters are a suffix. It's still not showing though.

Comment: Have you tried to decode it with utf-8? like `charTextView.setText(URLDecoder.decode(characters, HTTP.UTF-8));`

Comment: Just tried that, and no, that dosen't seem to be the problem.

Comment: And as a side note, why would i need to URLDecode it? it was fetched from a server that's true, but i can't see how that url*Encodes* it.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the url and connection and stuff, it just a tool for decoding, ignore the fact it comes from url-stuff package :D I used it for Cyrillic. Quick way to use utf-8 character set.

Comment: Ah a useful function in a strange place eh?

Comment: Does the font it's being rendered in have the tilde character defined?

Comment: Not sure how fonts operate on android, i'll have to look into that. I'm not even sure which font i have.

Comment: Yep. Try using typefaces and check for font

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably a font issue. The default font that comes with most Android devices doesn't properly support all Japanese characters: some kanji are shown using the Chinese glyph, more obscure characters are not displayed at all (boxes). You have a few options:

- if this is for your own use, and you have are rooted phone, install the DroidSansJapanese.ttf font (copy to `/system/fonts`)
- if it's an app you want to distribute, bundle the font in assets, and set your text views to use it